# Which of either of "too" and "so" to use in "His eyes were ...... bad that . . . "?

Tags: modifiers, intensifiers

I got this question from the [Cambridge website](http://www.cambridgeenglish.org/test-your-english/general-english/).

> His eyes were ...... bad that he couldn't read the number plate of the car in front.
>
> 1. such
> 2. too
> 3. so
> 4. very

I answered **too**, but the answer was **so**. Can anybody explain why please?

As far as I know **too** and **so** have the same meaning and the only difference is **too** can be used in negative.

**too**+ adjective / adverb (no noun)

**so**+ adjective / adverb (no noun)

Comment: You don't use **too** with a _that_ clause. Too is used when followed by a _to-infinitive_. For example, he is too young to understand this.

Comment: @Rose why is "such" wrong?

Comment: _such_ is correct when followed by a noun: He had such bad _eyes_ that .. .

Comment: "Such" is used before a noun or noun phrase and indicates similarity. Basically, you can think of it as "so much like". Example: "He had _such_ bad eyesight that...". "Too" is used in front of adjectives or adverbs to indicate excess in relation to something of comparison. Example "His eyes were _too_ bad _to read_...". "So" is like "too", but is used to indicate "enough" of an adjective/adverb to make something true. Example "His eyes were _so_ bad _that_ he couldn't read...". "Very" just means in excess, without any accompanying clauses. Example "His eyes were very bad".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

too = excessively

so  = to such a degree

> We serve only the freshest bread to our customers. This bread is *too stale* to be served.

It  has *gone beyond* or *exceeded* a certain degree of staleness.

> The bread was *so stale* that it was like a rock.

It has *reached* a certain degree of staleness.

**too {modifier} to ...**

**so {modifier} that ...**

The complement of **too {modifier}**  states something that is *impossible* because of the excessive degree:

> The price of the house was too good **to be true**.

The complement of **so {modifier}** states something that *correlates* with the  degree:

> The price was so good **(that) we bought the house immediately**.

Does the following fact *correlate* with having bad eyesight?

**he could not read the small print.**

Yes, it correlates.  Being *unable* to read small print is hardly *impossible* when your eyesight grows worse; it is what actually happens.

**His eyesight was __so__  bad, that he could not read the small print.**

Comment: Alternative, with "too": "His eyesight was *too* bad *to* read the small print".

Comment: Right. **to read the small print** is an *impossibility* if your eyesight is too bad for it.  **That he could not read the small print** is a *correlative* of his eyesight being **so bad**.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a particular quality to such a great extent that something isn't possible, you can express this idea by using either so or too, but the structure of the sentence in both cases will be different as follows:

So + adjective + that clause in the negative.

Too + adjective + to infinitive (without using a negative word)

So the correct sentences are:

His eyes were so bad that he couldn't read the number plate....

His eyes were too bad to read the number plate.

Comment: "Too + adjective + to infinitive (without using a negative word)" - except for examples like "The XYZ bank was too small not to fail". (The opposite of the original meme "too big to fail").